# LDAP authentication to retrieve users fullname

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, ldap

{ 
Please Help me in getting users given name in the below ldap authentication. the users is authenticating successfully but i couldn't get the users full name.

```
$ldaphost = 'localhost';  
$ldapport = 389;
$ds = ldap_connect($ldaphost, $ldapport) or die("Could not connect to our login server!");

ldap_set_option($ds, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
ldap_set_option($ds, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);
ldap_set_option(NULL, LDAP_OPT_DEBUG_LEVEL, 7);

if ($ds) 
{

    $upname = 'iap\\' . $username;

    $ldapbind = @ldap_bind($ds, $upname, $upasswd);

    if ($ldapbind) {
        //print "Congratulations! $username is authenticated.<BR><BR>";
        ldap_unbind( $ds ); 
        return true;
    } else { //print "$username  - Access Denied!<BR><BR>";
        return false;
    }
} else {
    return false;
}
```

}

?>}

Answer (score 0):

You can try this solution

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Connect to the LDAP server.
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
$ldap_connection = ldap_connect(LDAP_HOSTNAME);
if (FALSE === $ldap_connection){
    die("<p>Failed to connect to the LDAP server: ". LDAP_HOSTNAME ."</p>");
}

ldap_set_option($ldap_connection, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3) or die('Unable to set LDAP protocol version');
ldap_set_option($ldap_connection, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0); // We need this for doing an LDAP search.

if (TRUE !== ldap_bind($ldap_connection, $ldap_username, $ldap_password)){
    die('<p>Failed to bind to LDAP server.</p>');
}

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Get a list of all Active Directory users.
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
$ldap_base_dn = 'DC=xyz,DC=local';
$search_filter = "(&(objectCategory=person))";
$result = ldap_search($ldap_connection, $ldap_base_dn, $search_filter);
if (FALSE !== $result){
    $entries = ldap_get_entries($ldap_connection, $result);
    if ($entries['count'] > 0){
        $odd = 0;
        foreach ($entries[0] AS $key => $value){
            if (0 === $odd%2){
                $ldap_columns[] = $key;
            }
            $odd++;
        }
        echo '<table class="data">';
        echo '<tr>';
        $header_count = 0;
        foreach ($ldap_columns AS $col_name){
            if (0 === $header_count++){
                echo '<th class="ul">';
            }else if (count($ldap_columns) === $header_count){
                echo '<th class="ur">';
            }else{
                echo '<th class="u">';
            }
            echo $col_name .'</th>';
        }
        echo '</tr>';
        for ($i = 0; $i < $entries['count']; $i++){
            echo '<tr>';
            $td_count = 0;
            foreach ($ldap_columns AS $col_name){
                if (0 === $td_count++){
                    echo '<td class="l">';
                }else{
                    echo '<td>';
                }
                if (isset($entries[$i][$col_name])){
                    $output = NULL;
                    if ('lastlogon' === $col_name || 'lastlogontimestamp' === $col_name){
                        $output = date('D M d, Y @ H:i:s', ($entries[$i][$col_name][0] / 10000000) - 11676009600);
                    }else{
                        $output = $entries[$i][$col_name][0];
                    }
                    echo $output .'</td>';
                }
            }
            echo '</tr>';
        }
        echo '</table>';
    }
}
ldap_unbind($lda
```